# Require jspdf in webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I have a webpack + typescript env and I am trying to import `jspdf`. It looks like something wrong with the typings for it. I did:
`npm install --save @types/jspdf`

I've tried every one of:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
var jsPDF = require('jspdf');
import {jsPDF } from 'jspdf';
var jspdf = require('@types/jspdf');
```

Nothing works and webpack fails with `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jspdf'`

What is interesting is that right before I have:

```
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js';
```

which works. If I look at both modules sources, they are very different. So it is either `jspdf` is broken or I need another approach to import it. Which one is the correct assumption?

Comment: When you write import 'smth', webpack will search your files in module directorires with some extensions defined in your webpack config, change config or  import directly (import '@types/jspdf/index.d.ts')

Comment: @PetrAveryanov That's the thing: everything works but `jspdf`. I've also tried to import it directly and I think the error was `not a module`